# Printing HTML codes

Tags: php, html

I'm pretty new in PHP, this is a code in the comment.php file:

```
printf(
                    /* translators: 1: title. */
                    esc_html__( '<hr><Thoughts about '. get_the_title() .'<hr>', 'rainbowcats' ),
                    '<span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'usp_title',true) . '</span>'
                );
```

As you probably can guess, it prints the `<hr>`

Anyway around this? (Remember, I'm pretty new,  never used the command printf before..

Comment: Yes ! it prints like **Thoughts about [POST-TITLE]**

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I'm trying to format the comments, and also learning something while doing it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, your result shows your `<hr>` in text form.

When you're using `esc_html__( string $text, string $domain = 'default' )`, the returned output is escaped, it means :

- `"` is replaced with `&quot;`
- `&` is replaced with `&amp;`
- `<` is replaced with `&lt;`
- `>` is replaced with `&gt;`

So your `<hr>` are returning as text, not as html markups.

To fix that, you can simply move your `<hr>` outside of your `esc_html__()` :

```
<?php printf(
    '<hr>'.esc_html__( 'Thoughts about '. get_the_title(), 'rainbowcats' ).'<hr>';
); ?>
```

Furthermore, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with `'<span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'usp_title',true) . '</span>'` as an argument of `printf(format,arg)`, you should have called your arg with `%s` in your first parameter. But keep in mind to keep it outside `esc_html__()` !
For more information, see : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_printf.asp

Comment: So if I remove the esc_html__() in there, it will print it as HTML code?

Comment: Regarding the <span> issue,  that's not written by me, it's a plug-in that added that function..